# iOS Guidelines for Free vs. Paid apps

Tags: ios, app

A few months back, I was doing some recreational reading at the iOS Dev Center, and I came across a small list of guidelines for free vs. paid apps. It included guidance along these lines:

- How not to promote a paid version within a free version
- Not displaying "placeholder" buttons in a free version that "work" in a paid version

I can't remember much more than that, and I cannot find it anymore on the iOS Dev Center. It's possible I imagined it entirely, but I doubt it - does anyone have a link to this information, or have a set of guidelines for free vs. paid apps in the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find quite a few apps on the app store that do not quite follow those rules, especially games. The second point has been addressed by in app purchases.

The list you seem to be looking for is:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html

(You click on the right side of the iOS Dev Centre homepage, on Prepare for App Submission, and then on the left on the Tips section, just for your interest)

Comment: Yes! That's it. Perfect.